# PHP array within array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working? I'm trying to push an array into another array, but its only coming back with the last item from the $votes array.

```
foreach($json['area'] as $row) {
$name = $row['name'];
$group = $row['array']['group'];
$majority = $row['array']['majority'];
$candidates = $row['array']['candidates'];
foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
    $vote = $candidate["votes"];
    $candi = $candidate["name"];
    $votes = array("vote" => $vote, "candidate" => $candi);
}
$array = array("name" => $name, "group" => $group, "majority" => $majority, "votes" => $votes);

    $results[] = $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration of the outer loop is only producing a single `$votes` array , seemingly for a single candidate, in this line:

```
$votes = array("vote" => $vote, "candidate" => $candi);
```

If you want to capture multiple entries in that array for each row, you need to make it a multi-dimensional array also:

```
$candidates = $row['array']['candidates'];
$votes = [];
foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
    $votes[] = array(
        "vote"      => $candidate["votes"], 
        "candidate" => $candidate["name"]
    );
}

$array = array(
    "name"     => $name, 
    "group"    => $group, 
    "majority" => $majority, 
    "votes"    => $votes
);
```